# Windows API callback when executable is searched

Tags: shell, winapi

Is there a hook in the Windows API that allows one to extend the behavior when an executable is searched on the `%PATH%` and return a custom filepath of a file that might not be on the `%PATH%`?

Comment: Simple answer is no. You are attempting to write malware.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I am attempting to write an application that will keep my PC more organised, but thanks for the accusation, dude. Lova ya too

Comment: You might not mean it to be used in a bad way, but it is still malware.

Comment: According to the [Wikipedia definition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Malware), "Malware [...] is software used to disrupt computer operation, gather sensitive information, or gain access to private computer systems." I can't see how this applys to my intention.

Comment: Malware detection does not detect intent. Any good malware detection would object to programs that interfere with search path dynamically. Anyway, you presumably realise now that there is no way for you to get such a hook.

Answer (score 2):

[The CreateProcess docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682425%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) document how Windows searches for executables:

> 1. The directory from which the application loaded.
> 2. The current directory for the parent process.
> 3. The 32-bit Windows system directory. Use the [`GetSystemDirectory`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724373%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function to get the path of this directory.
> 4. The 16-bit Windows system directory. There is no function that obtains the path of this directory, but it is searched. The name of this directory is System.
> 5. The Windows directory. Use the [`GetWindowsDirectory`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724454%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function to get the path of this directory.
> 6. The directories that are listed in the PATH environment variable. Note that this function does not search the per-application path specified by the **App Paths** registry key. To include this per-application path in the search sequence, use the [`ShellExecute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762153%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function.

Assuming we're talking about your own app trying to execute some other EXE that might not be on the path, specify the path you want to search in the App Paths registry key and use `ShellExecute` as instructed in #6. Otherwise, I'm not aware of any "normal" way to hook executable searching; such a thing would probably be considered a security risk, since a malicious app could trap common %PATH% searches such as `cmd` and return the filename of a different app. You'd probably have to look into writing a [File System Filter Driver](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff557282%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: Thank you for this detailed answer. I find it very hard navigating through MSDN and finding what you actually search for, sorry for not finding it myself. Guess I'm gonna look into the File System Filter Driver stuff.